# Anylogic System Modelling, using excel table for database

Tags: database, excel, system, modeling, anylogic

May somebody can help me?! 
I´m usind Anylogic. There is a population (=stock), separeted in 10 difference groups (depening on the age). I want to use this for my structure. 
I have already the excel table in my structure but I don´t know, how i can use it. Or is it better if I use the "tablefuntion"?!
I couldn´t found any good tutorial about this. There are only examples where you just have one number. 
E.g. stock: starting value = 10000.
But I need stock: starting value = Group1: 50, Group2: 30, Group3: 20.

May somebody can help me?! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please clarify what your current model looks like and what you want to achieve? Ideally with some screen shots... In general, a system dynamics stock can only take one kind of "fluid" (i.e. population), sounds like you want it to process 10?

Comment: @Benjamin I assume he's using array stocks. See my answer.

Comment: BTW, your question title is a little misleading/vague. Maybe something like "Initialising an AnyLogic array stock using Excel data" would be better?

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you're using an array stock, where the array is of a ten-value AnyLogic dimension.

If you hit the `Edit...` button for the initial value, you'll see that they are specified in Java notation `{v1, v2, ..., v10}` where v1 is the initial value for the 1st dimension alternative, etc. (Confusingly, this is Java array notation which is different to an array *stock*.)

There is no straightforward way to initialise these from Excel data. With AnyLogic 7.2+ you can fairly easily get Excel values into an AnyLogic database table but, unlike for basic AnyLogic variables or parameters, there is no visual wizard to set up a query to populate a stock's initial value.

Probably your best bet is to import the Excel worksheet into an AnyLogic database table and then, in the startup code for your model, explicitly loop through setting the 10 values via queries. You can use the `set` method (function) on the stock to set each value (which has two arguments: the value to set and then the number of the dimensional alternative to set).

**Example**

See the AnyLogic help `Database --> Importing database tables` for how to import your Excel worksheet as a table.

Let's say your table is called `stock_vals` with columns `stock_name` (identifying the stock that the values are for), `val1`, `val2`, etc. (giving the `double` values for dimension entry 1, 2, etc.).

Then let's say your array stock is called `population` with an `AgeRange` dimension with alternatives `YOUNG`, `MIDDLE_AGED` and `OLD` (alternatives 1, 2 and 3 -- I just used three alternatives to make it simpler). Then assume in your table you have entries

`"population", 100.0, 200.0, 300.0`

Then you can use the following code in your startup logic:

```
stock.set(selectFrom(stock_vals).where(stock_vals.stock_name.eq("population")).uniqueResult(stock_vals.val1), 1);
stock.set(selectFrom(stock_vals).where(stock_vals.stock_name.eq("population")).uniqueResult(stock_vals.val2), 2);
stock.set(selectFrom(stock_vals).where(stock_vals.stock_name.eq("population")).uniqueResult(stock_vals.val3), 3);
```

The AnyLogic `Database --> Querying` help shows how this database selection Java code works.

The above code could be tidied up / made more elegant but that's the essence.